# How to execute a JSON function every 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, json

This is the JSON function:

```
$.post("server.php", { "id": "studentid" },
   function(data){  
     if(data.route)
     {
        window.location = data.location
     }

   }, 
   "json");
```

This redirects the user when a page gives a data.route . How can I make this function execute every 2 seconds so the page changes when that file changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) method:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    // sending AJAX POST requests every 2 seconds to the server
    // and if the server responds with data.route != null redirect
    $.post('server.php', { id: 'studentid' },
        function(data) {
            if(data.route) {
                window.location = data.location;
            }
        }, 
   'json');
}, 2000);
```

Comment: I posted it in a <script></script> in the <head></head> and it does not works... I am stuck :|

Comment: @Octavian, `it does not works... I am stuck` is a phrase that is commonly employed by people not understanding or caring about how computer works. Software developers usually provide much more details such as the exact errors they are getting, the FireBug trace of the Request/Response, ... You get my point?

Comment: @Octavian, great, what was the problem?

Answer (score 6):

```
window.setInterval(function(){$.post ... }, 2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

See [setInterval(code,millis)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), e.g.:

```
setInterval("myUpdateFunction()", 2000);
```